# Rails constants unloaded from initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom initializer `config/initializers/api/v1.rb`, in which I set some global constants for use accross the application:

```
module Api
  module V1
    DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d' 
  end
end
```

The first time I hit a controller that users `Api::V1::DATE_FORMAT`, everything works as expected. If I hit that path again, I get a `NameError uninitialized constant Api::V1::DATE_FORMAT`.

The [Rails documentation for configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) explicitly says it should handle this case:

> You can use subfolders to organize your initializers if you like,
>   because Rails will look into the whole file hierarchy from the
>   initializers folder on down.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and the associated line of code that's throwing the error?

Comment: It happens everywhere from ApplicationHelper to the Rails console, anywhere one of these constants is mentioned. So it isn't a particular place in the code, but the unloading of constants

Comment: I just tested on a vanilla rails-3.2.13 app in the rails console, and was able to keep printing out `Api::V1::DATE_FORMAT` over and over. I suspect that there's some code that's modifying this value (which should print out a warning that it's already initialized).

Comment: grep for `DATE_FORMAT` and see what it says? Should be able to track down any duplicate assignment.

Comment: It is only defined once. I think the issue is that the controller is also in the Api::V1 namespace and when it reloads the classes in development, the constants get undefined? Does that make sense?